# Trying to Generate Random Picture with PIL, but get strange result

Tags: python, image, python-imaging-library

[Generated Pictured](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lY81n.jpg)

[image]

I used this code to generate a random picture by filling out each pixel, but why I got this strange output (picture at the above link)? There are parallel red, green, blue vertical lines in the picture.

```
#<Python 3.8>
from PIL import Image
import numpy as np
data=np.random.randint(low=0,high=256,size=128*128*3)
data=data.reshape(128,128,3)
Image.fromarray(data,'RGB')
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

PIL's RGB mode expects 8-bit color channels, but your array most likely has a dtype of `int32`. 75% of each of your integers are composed of unused 0 bits, which is why 75% of your image is black stripes.

Try setting your data's `dtype` to `unit8` when you call `randint`.

```
from PIL import Image
import numpy as np
data=np.random.randint(low=0,high=256,size=128*128*3, dtype=np.uint8)
data=data.reshape(128,128,3)
Image.fromarray(data,'RGB').save("output.png")
```

Result (one possibility of many):

[image]

Comment: Thanks! It makes sense!